# Is the protein in teardrops still attached to cells, or is it released and free-flowing?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, proteins

A [ScienceDaily article](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/01/120119143332.htm?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20sciencedaily%20%28ScienceDaily%3a%20Latest%20Science%20News%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader) says that the protein in teardrops can kill bacteria.

But how does it reach the bacteria?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question.

According to the article you mention the proteins in teardrops kill the bacteria which are invading the eye (e.g. also present in the teardrops):

> "Those jaws chew apart the walls of the bacteria that are trying to
>   get into your eyes and infect them,"

**EDIT**: These proteins are enzymes called [lysozymes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysozyme). Those are free-flowing proteins of the human tears. These proteins are actively produces in the lacrimal glands and actively [secreted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secreted) into the [lacrimal liquid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tears).

Comment: Basically, I'm wondering: are these proteins in teardrops free-flowing? Or are they still attached to cells in the teardrops?

Comment: I added information about these proteins into the question.